# Azure DefaultAzureCredential mocking in Xunit

Tags: c#, azure, xunit.net

I have below code which uses DefaultAzureCredentials to get the Access token . The unit test give me token when running from Visual studio because the logged in user has access. the same code fails in devops pipeline as the agent created dynamically.

private async Task AcquireManagementAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
var scope = _configuration.GetValue("Azure:ArmAuthScope");

```
        bool userManagedIdentity;
        bool.TryParse(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Azure:UseManagedIdentity"), out userManagedIdentity);

        
        AccessToken token = new AccessToken();            
        
        //using Managed Identity
        if (userManagedIdentity)
        {
            try
            {
        
                token = await new DefaultAzureCredential().GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope }), cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger?.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }           
       
        return token;
    }
```

How do I make my test code to run on devops? I want to mock this.

Comment: If you're using the real values then you're doing an integration test and not a unit test.
For unit testing, you should mock it. For integration testing, try using a WebApplicationFactory

Comment: How do we mock? do you have any samples ?

Comment: Here’s a specific answer that should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434067/how-to-unit-test-defaultazurecredential-method.

Comment: The above link stated code changes does not work.

Comment: Does not work how? Any further information on the errors? Any updated code etc